# On Cisco IOS XE routers, do classes in service policies have their own queues by default?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, qos, cisco-router

I'm configuring a C1111-4p (Cisco IOS XE 17.12.02) router for home use.

I want to prevent some torrent clients from disrupting the internet for other clients (calls, web browsing, etc).

I've setup some class-maps and added them to policies. Then, I added those policies as service-policy on the WAN interface. The matching is working fine but I don't know if it's actually doing something. I don't know if each class has its own queue or not.

This is part of the config (I removed some classes to save space on this post):

```
policy-map WEBUI-MARKING-IN
 class WEBUI-VOICE-NBAR
  set dscp ef
 class WEBUI-BULK_DATA-NBAR
  set dscp af11
 class WEBUI-SCAVENGER-NBAR
  set dscp cs1
 class class-default
  set dscp default
policy-map WEBUI-QUEUING-OUT
 class WEBUI-QUEUING-OUT1_ADV_UI_CLASS
 class WEBUI-QUEUING-OUT2_ADV_UI_CLASS
 class WEBUI-QUEUING-OUT3_ADV_UI_CLASS
 class WEBUI-SCAVENGER-NBAR

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip nbar protocol-discovery
 ip nat outside
 service-policy input WEBUI-MARKING-IN
 service-policy output WEBUI-QUEUING-OUT
```

I got my Internet connection from my tv cable company (DOCSIS 3.x), and the bandwidth is 600mbps/50mbps.

I've been reading about QoS, but most (or all?) of the options require specifying an upload/download bandwidth, something that, in my case, is pretty hard as the network speed isn't stable or guaranteed (it isn't a dedicated fiber link).

**To summarize:**

- Classifying the traffic does something on its own?
- Is there a recommended QoS / Queuing that can work in my case?
- Can I throttle the incoming traffic by dropping/delaying TCP ACKs?

Thanks!